C-Wire Identification in a 40 year old furnace
Our HVAC system is a 1 stage heating and 1 stage cooling. The furnace is GE Ambassador II Model BLU080F942B1 manufactued in 1981. Our system was wired with only R G W and Y. I was trying to install Honeywell T9. I had an electrician come and run a wire from the thermostat to the furnace.
After research online, I felt that the blue wire that is capped would be the 24vac return, however this did not result in the thermostat working, and a loud clank could be heard when the pins made contact, but the thermostat never powered on. (I promptly disconnected the connection and the system still works with the original thermostat.)
I have a suspicion one of the three wire nuts would be my 24vac return, but I cannot discern which is which. What should be my next attempt at connecting 24vac return?  I'll attach pictures of the visible wires and the wiring diagram.






Are you sure the box in the bottom photo is your 24V transformer? You may have to trace more wiring until you find the transformer...

You are right that the Blue should be the 24V- Common.
But be careful about colors, since you have another blue (high voltage) that is capped.
The 24V-Common Blue is thin wire (gauge 18)
None of your pictures show the 24 Volt transformer.

I found the transformer and I was able to connect thermostat to the first wire nut from 24vac side of transformer. However, this wire nut also connects to AGR/PR and when i power on the unit with the T9 thermostat attached, the unit starts running heat (i hear clicking of the gas trying to light). Would connecting directly to transformer help?

@EvanW. I am blind here, show me a picture, and yes connecting directly to transformer should work.

I would follow the thin blue wire back to the transformer from the AGV-Automatic Gas Valve or from the PR-Pilot Relay. If you have an attached AC coil, it should be one of the 2 thin wires going to the outdoor AC unit to control the relay in the outdoor unit that turns it on.  This YouTube Video may help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9r7mxCxR36A . At 8:33 in the video it shows what appears to be the 120VAC to 24VAC low voltage transformer on top of the box which contains the thermostat wiring terminal board, just below and right of the silver pressure switch.  The thick blue wire near the fan capacitor is one of the high voltage speed selection wires. The motor lists which color wire to connect to obtain the correct fan speed,  The unused wires are capped off as they will be live with voltage through the motor windings when the blower is energized.
